# Android: Problem with the Path Style in Region.Op 

Tags: android, path, region

My basic goal is to subtract a Path from a predetermined region (also created with a Path) in Android 1.6.

Is there anyway to get Region.setPath to treat the path passed to it the same way the canvas treats a stroked path (which is what my users are seeing)?

I understand that the Style is used for Painting to the canvas, but I need the behavior to reflect what is drawn on canvas and the path being drawn is Stroked.

The behavior works find when adding shapes to the path (path.addRect, path.addCircle), but not when using lineTo, quadTo, cubeTo. My only other option is to compose a path of nothing but rects or circles.

```
public class ComplexRegions extends Activity {

static Display display;

/** Code Sample for StackOverflow */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));             
}

private static class SampleView extends View {      
    Path orig_path, finger_path;
    Paint dirty_paint, fingerpaint, temp_paint;
    Region orig_region, clip, fingerregion, tempregion;
    Canvas c;
    int h, w;

    public float mX, mY, dx, dy;
    boolean b;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        fingerregion = new Region();
        tempregion = new Region();
        orig_region = new Region();
        clip = new Region();
        orig_path = new Path();
        finger_path = new Path();

        dirty_paint = new Paint();
        dirty_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        dirty_paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        dirty_paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        dirty_paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        dirty_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        dirty_paint.setAntiAlias(false);

        fingerpaint = new Paint();
        fingerpaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        fingerpaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        fingerpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        fingerpaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        fingerpaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        fingerpaint.setAntiAlias(false);

        temp_paint = new Paint();
        temp_paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        temp_paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        temp_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        temp_paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        temp_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        temp_paint.setAntiAlias(false);

        w = display.getWidth();
        h = display.getHeight();  
        clip.set(0, 0, w, h);

        orig_path.addRect(w*0.25f, h*0.55f, w*0.65f, h*0.65f, Path.Direction.CW);
        orig_region.setPath(orig_path, clip);           
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {                       
        c.drawPath(orig_path, dirty_paint);
        c.drawPath(finger_path, fingerpaint);    
        //following line shows that finger_path is 
        //behaving as though fill and stroke is on
        //after being passed to the region class
        c.drawPath(tempregion.getBoundaryPath(), temp_paint);            
        invalidate();
    }

    //L T R B
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();  

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
        return true;         
}

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        finger_path.moveTo(x, y);
        //finger_path.addCircle(x, y, 25, Path.Direction.CCW);
        //when addCircle is only Path method used on path the result is fine
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y){
        finger_path.lineTo(x, y);     
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        //*PROBLEM* Seems like setPath forces finger_path to default to fill and stroke
        fingerregion.setPath(finger_path, clip); 
        //set tempregion to the region resulting from this Op
        tempregion.op(orig_region, fingerregion, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
        //check if the resulting region is empty
        if(tempregion.isEmpty()){
            for(int i = 0;i<100;i++)
                Log.e("CR", "Region Completely Covered.");
        }
    }
}
```

}